# How to generate current file header comment after creation with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

As we know IntelliJ support code template
`Settings path: Editor > Code Style > File and Code Templates`
it's easy to generate some default file header comments via the IntelliJ predefined variables,

```
${PACKAGE_NAME}   name of the package in which the new file is created
${USER}           current user system login name
${DATE}           current system date
${TIME}           current system time 
etc ...
```

My question is how to generate current class file full name while creating new file? e.g.

```
/**
 * Created on 1/11/15.
 * Class: MyApp.java
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Class template to something like this:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
/**
 * Created on ${DATE}.
 * Class: ${NAME}.java
 */
public class ${NAME} { 
}
```

(As a personal remark, I don't see any use in that, because when you open a file, you already know its name; there is no reason to duplicate this information in the comment.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, cuz full classname is helpful for javadoc.

Comment: No, it's not helpful for javadoc either. The Javadoc for a class already includes its name; there is no need to duplicate this information.